# python define names as a constant global name is not defined

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 (pycharm) and I set up global names in "constants.py" and after import constants in the main program, it doesn't recognize it.

project/folder/constants.py:

```
    DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

    LOCAL = 'local'
    .......
```

project/main.py:

```
from constants import *

if config['masterUrl'] == LOCAL: .....
```

error:

```
 if config['masterUrl'] == LOCAL:
NameError: global name 'LOCAL' is not defined
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are constants.py and main.py are in the same folder?

Comment: @AndreyF no they are not.

Comment: Why the indentation of your constant values in `constants.py`?

Comment: @displayname can you explain your question?

Comment: constants and main.py must be in same folder for least!

Comment: @AndreyF She must have got an `ImportError` in the first place!

Comment: @UbdusSamad maybe the OP has another constants file...

Comment: try to change your import to: `from folder.constants import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constants in the project like this:

`from project.folder.constants import *`

And you need `__init__.py` in the project dir.

The namespace path in python is absolutly. What I mean:

```
project
  -- app1
    -- constants.py
  -- app2
  -- module2
__init__.py
main.py
```

main.py

```
from project.app1.constants import *
```

It's not scala or cpp